# How to provision Azure virtual networks and VM from the Python SDK (using Azure Service Mode)?

Tags: python, networking, azure, cloud

I am using the [Windows Azure SDK for Python](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/python/common-tasks/install-python/) to provision Linux VMs from a Python program using the [Service Management](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/python/how-to-guides/service-management/) API.

Apparently Azure makes it possible to connect VMs directly in a single virtual network:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/networking/add-a-vm-to-a-virtual-network/

This feature is exposed in the REST API, for instance to create a new VM:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj157181

and to create a new VM deployment in a given virtual network:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj157194

However by reading the source code of the Python SDK, it seems that this feature is not exposed in the Python API:

https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/src/azure/servicemanagement/servicemanagementservice.py#L850

Is this a known issue? How to provision Azure virtual networks and VM from a Python program? Do I have to generate the XML of the network and the VM deployment by my-self instead?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is a known issue: https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/79

> When creating a virtual machine with
>   create_virtual_machine_deployment, you cannot specify a
>   VirtualNetworkName for the delpoyed VM.
>
> Possible fix : . add virtual_network_name=None parameter in
>   create_virtual_machine_deployment and
>   virtual_machine_deployment_to_xml and set VirtualNetworkName in xml
>   (right after ) if virtual_network_name: xml+=
>   _XmlSerializer.data_to_xml([('VirtualNetworkName', virtual_network_name)])